# Using Vue.js: disabling button on picture slideshow, when no "next" photo is available

Tags: javascript, vue.js

This is my first time using Vue. I am trying to create a slideshow from an array of images. I have am able to disable my "previous" button, when the user is at the beginning of the slideshow, but cannot disable my "next" button when at the last image of the slide show.

Here is my code:

```js
Vue.config.devtools = true
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    title: 'Photo of the day!',
    description: '',
    images:   [
    {
      image: 'https://cdn.spacetelescope.org/archives/images/wallpaper2/heic1509a.jpg', date: '1/9/2019', title: 'Beautiful Milky Way'
    },
    {
      image: 'https://img.purch.com/w/660/aHR0cDovL3d3dy5zcGFjZS5jb20vaW1hZ2VzL2kvMDAwLzA2MS8wNzUvb3JpZ2luYWwvY2hhbmRyYS1uZ2M2MzU3LWNvbXBvc2l0ZS5qcGc=', date: '1/10/2019', title: 'Amazing Whirlpool Galaxy'
    },
    {
      image: 'https://icdn3.digitaltrends.com/image/space-engine-featured-510x0.jpg?ver=1', date: '1/11/2019', title: 'Wonderous Large Magellanic Cloud'
    },

  ],
    currentNumber: 0,
    photosAvailable: true,
  }, 
  methods: {
    next: function() {
      app.currentNumber += 1;
      if (app.currentNumber  === app.images.length) {
        console.log('SERGIO')
        app.photosAvailable = false 
        return 
      }
    },
    previous: function() {
      app.photosAvailable = true
      return app.currentNumber -= 1
    }, 
  }
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="./styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Anaheim" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>NASA Photo Of The Day</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='app'>
      <section class='hero'>
      <h1 class='title'>{{ title }}</h1>
    </section>
    <section class='picture-area'>
      <div class='info'>
        <h2>{{ images[currentNumber].title }}</h2>
        <p v-bind='description'>{{ description }}</p>
        <img class='image-of-day' :src='images[currentNumber].image' />
        <p class='date'>{{ images[currentNumber].date }}</p>
        <button :disabled="!currentNumber" v-on:click="previous" class='backward'>previous</button>
        <button :disabled="!photosAvailable" v-on:click="next" :class="{disabledButton: !photosAvailable}" class='forward'>next</button>
      </div>
    </section>
    </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios@0.12.0/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
  <script src='./index.js'></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

In my Vue devtools, I can see that photosAvailable does turn to false, which should change the button to disabled, but it is not.

Hope someone can catch my error, as it is my first time using Vue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach that you can use to make it work including the parts that you should improve on your current code.

- Replace `app` with `this` under your methods since using `app` will cause an error since it's `undefined`. Use `this` if you want to get access to any state or method under your component.
- Since the status of the next and prev buttons are derived from the value of `currentNumber` of slide, you can define `isPrevPhotoAvailable` and `isNextPhotoAvailable` methods under the `computed` property of your component. With this, you can remove `isPhotosAvailable` from your state.

```js
Vue.config.devtools = true
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    title: 'Photo of the day!',
    description: '',
    images:   [
    {
      image: 'https://cdn.spacetelescope.org/archives/images/wallpaper2/heic1509a.jpg', date: '1/9/2019', title: 'Beautiful Milky Way'
    },
    {
      image: 'https://img.purch.com/w/660/aHR0cDovL3d3dy5zcGFjZS5jb20vaW1hZ2VzL2kvMDAwLzA2MS8wNzUvb3JpZ2luYWwvY2hhbmRyYS1uZ2M2MzU3LWNvbXBvc2l0ZS5qcGc=', date: '1/10/2019', title: 'Amazing Whirlpool Galaxy'
    },
    {
      image: 'https://icdn3.digitaltrends.com/image/space-engine-featured-510x0.jpg?ver=1', date: '1/11/2019', title: 'Wonderous Large Magellanic Cloud'
    },

  ],
    currentNumber: 0
  }, 
  computed: {
    isNextPhotoAvailable: function() {
      return this.currentNumber + 1  !== this.images.length;
    },
    isPrevPhotoAvailable: function() {
      return this.currentNumber - 1  !== -1;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    next: function() {
      this.currentNumber += 1;
    },
    previous: function() {
      return this.currentNumber -= 1;
    }, 
  }
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="./styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Anaheim" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>NASA Photo Of The Day</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='app'>
      <section class='hero'>
      <h1 class='title'>{{ title }}</h1>
    </section>
    <section class='picture-area'>
      <div class='info'>
        <h2>{{ images[currentNumber].title }}</h2>
        <p v-bind='description'>{{ description }}</p>
        <img class='image-of-day' :src='images[currentNumber].image' />
        <p class='date'>{{ images[currentNumber].date }}</p>
        <button :disabled="!isPrevPhotoAvailable" v-on:click="previous" class='backward'>previous</button>
        <button :disabled="!isNextPhotoAvailable" v-on:click="next" :class="{disabledButton: !isNextPhotoAvailable}" class='forward'>next</button>
      </div>
    </section>
    </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios@0.12.0/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
  <script src='./index.js'></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try putting the logic in computed?